# How to sign SHA256 hash and verify it using bouncy castle?

Tags: java, hash, digital-signature, bouncycastle, sha256

I'm trying to sign SHA256 hash of a base64 encoded json string and validate it against the signature generated.

I'm using the below code to sign the hash:

**Required output**: PKCS#7 signature of SHA-256 hash of Base64 of payload JSON using private key

```
String input="Base64encodedJsonData";
byte[] hashedData = DigestUtils.sha256(input.getBytes()); 

   ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256WithRSA").build(privateKey);
    Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate("KEY_ALIAS");

    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();        
    JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder jcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build());
    generator.addSignerInfoGenerator(jcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder.build(signer,(X509Certificate) cert));

    CMSTypedData cmsdata = new CMSProcessableByteArray(hashedData);
    CMSSignedData signeddata = generator.generate(cmsdata,true);
    byte[] signedBytes= signeddata.getEncoded();
        String encrypted = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signedBytes);
```

Verification:I'm using the below code to verify the signed data.It is returning false,which indicates invalid signature.

```
        boolean verifiedStatus = false;

byte[] signedBytes = Base64
                .decodeBase64(encrypted.getBytes());
        cmsSignedData = new CMSSignedData(
                new CMSProcessableByteArray(hashedData)),
                signedBytes);
        Store certStore = cmsSignedData.getCertificates();
        SignerInformationStore signers = cmsSignedData.getSignerInfos();
        Iterator signersIterator = signers.getSigners().iterator();
        while (signersIterator.hasNext()) {
            SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation) signersIterator
                    .next();
            Collection certCollection = certStore
                    .getMatches(signer.getSID());
            Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
            X509CertificateHolder certHolder = (X509CertificateHolder) certIt
                    .next();
            X509Certificate x509Certificate = new JcaX509CertificateConverter()
                    .setProvider(BC).getCertificate(certHolder);
            verifiedStatus = signer
                    .verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder()
                            .setProvider(BC).build(x509Certificate));//returning false
```

If I sign the base64 encoded string directly(without hashing),its returning true.I'm I missing something in the above code? Is there any different way to sign the SHA256 hash using bouncy castle?

Comment: `SHA256WithRSA` signature algorithm includes the hashing operation, so you are computing the hash twice. Removing `DigestUtils.sha256(input.getBytes());` is correct. But I do not understand the background of your question. Why are you building a CMS signature? There are simpler and clearer options to sign a JSON

Comment: @pedrofb OP is not using the computed hash (variable encrypted).

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @pedrofb  I'm using USB token signature to sign.I need to generate PKCS7 from signed data. So I'm using CMS  signature. Please suggest any simpler way to sign the hash.

Comment: [JSON Web Signature (JWS)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7515)  is specially designed for JSON, but if you need PKCS#7, then bouncycastle is needed.

Comment: The hash is simply generated internally, as pedrofb has indicated. Is there a reason why this doesn't suffice? If so, please include it in the question. As it currently stands, it seems your question is already answered in the comment section.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Actually I have a validation tool. For that I need to pass SHA256 hash of Base64 encoded json and the signed data.The result of the validation should be true.But now it is returning false as I'm hashing the data twice. As SHA256WithRSA algorithm will hash the data internally,I'm not getting the hash value to validate using the validator. Is there any different way to sign the hash directly by skipping the internal hashing?